# Android ActionBar vs ToolBar

Tags: android-actionbar, android-toolbar

Can you make Android new Toolbar to be shown with shadow like you could do with the old ActionBar?

Please refer to the image: Left is ActionBar and you can see it looks "floating" with shadow while the right one is ToolBar, how can you show it the same?

[image: Toolbar vs ActionBar]

Answer (score 2):

Use attibute `android:elevetion=4dp` on toolbar.