# Android ActionBar and Toolbar are not seen even when defined in xml

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-framelayout, android-actionbar-compat

I have this layout and Fragment class:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/non_clickable_account_snackbar_constraint_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/my_title"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      />
  <mylButton
      android:id="@+id/show_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:text="@string/show"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

and

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment {

  @Inject
  public myFragment() {}

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(
      LayoutInflater layoutInflater, @Nullable ViewGroup viewGroup, @Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    View view =
        layoutInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.my_fragment, viewGroup, false /* attachToRoot */);

    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.account_snackbar_title);
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    return view;
  }
```

}

I see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829746/android-actionbar-vs-toolbar) about the visual difference between ActionBar and a Toolbar.

However I don't seem to see any of them, just a blank page with a button.

[image]

Comment: You have the `Toolbar`'s height as `wrap_content`. With nothing in it, it'll wrap to zero height. It looks like you're trying to add some "content" to it – i.e., with the `android:text` attribute, and the support `ActionBar` calls – but those aren't working as you're expecting. The `android:text` attribute does nothing for `Toolbar`, and those support `ActionBar` calls are ineffective because you've not set that `Toolbar` as the support `ActionBar` first.

Comment: Thanks, 
`because you've not set that Toolbar as the support ActionBar`
these are not two separated things? Toolbar vs ActionBar

Comment: I might have misinterpreted your intent. I had assumed that the `getSupportActionBar()` lines you have in `onCreateView()` were attempts to get that `Toolbar` to show up. Anyhoo, the issue is likely still the same; the `wrap_content` height is wrapping to zero. I'm not sure of the design you want, ultimately, but you could change that `android:text` attribute to `android:title` to get that set, and/or change the `android:layout_height` to a definite measure – e.g., `"?actionBarSize"`, `"20dp"`, etc. – so it doesn't shrink to nothing, etc. Might need a background color, too.

Comment: That solved my problem. I was missing; `activity.setSupportActionBar(view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar));` can you please add as an answer?

Comment: Oh, it's cool. I'm not really sure what your whole setup is, because I would've expected one of those arrangements to crash, so I don't wanna cement that advice in an answer if it might cause issues for future users with similar problems. :-) Please feel free to post an answer yourself, if you like. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `@Mike M.` comment I have noticed my toolbar wasn't getting the content I wanted it to get.

**For setting title from xml:**

I should have replaced "android:setText" with [android:setTitle](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar?hl=en#setTitle(int))

**For setting title from code:**

I was missing getting the toolbar view:

```
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
activity.setSupportActionBar(view.findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar));
activity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.show);
activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```